# Bootstrap Best Practices for Class Tags and Multiple View Ports

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Just getting into Bootstrap 3 and was wondering what best practices are regarding class tags for multiple viewports. For example, just to offset my `navbar-brand` it looks like the following which just seems messy (but I guess this is one of the complaints regarding Bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-xl-11 col-xl-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
```

Seems like there is a better and more concise way to write this will retaining the dynamic elements for each viewport size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple answer is**  - Think mobile first

```
<div class="col-xl-11 col-xl-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
```

is the same as

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
```

So, first apply rules starting from the `-xs` smaller size and move towards `-lg` (or xl in your case)

---

**Example**

Let's say you want an full width element on mobile `-xs`, 3/4 on the desktop `-md` and half width on `-lg`. What you should come up with is

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
```

Note that you don't define `col-xs-12` because it **will be set by default** for you. For the `-sm` in this case will also be `col-sm-12` set by default

---

For the more info please read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to set the size for each of the screen sizes, just 1 for mobile and 1 for desktop and if you really want to, use 2 different sizes for desktop if that's what you want.
Another tip I can give you is to you the `container-fluid`
so it will fill automatically to the parent size